Delay problem in python/mysql integration
I'm making a python interface that has a user registration and login part using Mysql. I made a class to register and another to perform the login which worked normally, then I tried to apply encryption to the data using Mysql's AES_ENCRYPT and AES_DECRYPT functions, this also worked well, it is registering with the encryption. But there was a problem on the login screen, when I register the user the interface closes the registration screen and opens the login screen, then I type the user and password that I saved and that is already in the database, but it falls into my user not found check, even though it is in the database, then if I close the interface and run it again, the same user and password that was given as not found now works, it is as if there was a delay problem in querying the database, what can it be in this case? Below I'll put the parts of the classes that refer to registration and login.
Login:
connection = mysql.connector.connect(
 host='localhost',
 user='root',
 password='27061999',
 database='projectofinep',
)

class Ui_Login(object):
 def __init__(self):
   self.cursor = conexao.cursor()
   self.attempts = 0
   command = 'SELECT key FROM encryption WHERE encryption id=1'
   self.cursor.execute(command)
   result = self.cursor.fetchone()
   self.encryption_key = result[0]

 def disable_campos(self):
   self.email_field.setEnabled(False)
   self.password_field.setEnabled(False)
   self.pushButton.setEnabled(False)
   QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(10000, self.enable_fields)

 def enable_campos(self):
   self.email_field.setEnabled(True)
   self.password_field.setEnabled(True)
   self.pushButton.setEnabled(True)
   self.attempts = 0

 def Home_Screen(self, Login):
   # Validate the number of attempts
   if self.attempts >= 3:
     self.show_error_message("Too many failed attempts. Please try again in 10 seconds.")
     self.desabilitar_campos()
     return

   # Validate email and password fields before closing the login screen
   if not self.validate_email(self.email_field.text()):
     self.show_error_message("Invalid username")
     return
 
  if not self.validate_password(self.password_field.text()):
     self.show_error_message("Invalid password")
     return

 # Query the database to check username and password
 command = f"""
 SELECT
 CAST(AES_DECRYPT(user, '{self.encryption_key}') AS CHAR),
 CAST(AES_DECRYPT(password, '{self.encryption_key}') AS CHAR)
 FROM cadastro_usuarios
 WHERE CAST(AES_DECRYPT(usuario, '{self.encryption_key}') AS CHAR) = '{self.email_field.text()}'
 """
 self.cursor.execute(command)
 result = self.cursor.fetchone()

 if result is None:
   self.show_error_message("User not found")
   self.attempts += 1
   return

 bank_user, bank_password = result

 if self.email_field.text() == bank_user and self.password_field.text() == bank_password:
   # Opens next screen if login is successful
   self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
   self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
   self.ui.setupUi(self.window, self.email_field.text())
   self.window.show()
   self.cursor.close()
   connection.close()
   Login.close()
 else:
   self.show_error_message("Incorrect password")
   self.attempts += 1
   return

Registration:
connection = mysql.connector.connect(
 host='localhost',
 user='root',
 password='27061999',
 database='projectofinep',
)

class Ui_Usuario(object):
 def __init__(self):
   self.image = 'doctor.png'
   self.cursor = conexao.cursor()
   command = 'SELECT key FROM encryption WHERE encryption id=1'
   self.cursor.execute(command)
   result = self.cursor.fetchone()
   self.encryption_key = result[0]

 def Save(self, User):
   if not self.validate_full_name(self.full_name.text()):
   self.show_error_message("Invalid username")
   return

 if not self.validate_email(self.email_field.text()):
   self.show_error_message("Invalid email")
   return

 if self.comboBox_4.currentText() == "Security Question":
   self.show_error_message("Select a security question")
   return

 if not self.validate_resposta(self.resposta.text()):
   self.show_error_message("Invalid response")
   return

 if not self.validate_password(self.password_field.text()):
   self.show_error_message("Your password must be at least:\n 6 digits\n     One uppercase letter\n One lowercase letter\n One special character (#@!&)")
   return

 if not self.validate_password(self.password_field_2.text()):
   self.show_error_message("Your password confirmation must be at   least:\n 6 digits\n One uppercase letter\n One lowercase letter\n One special character (#@!&)")
   return

 if self.password_field.text() != self.password_field_2.text():
   self.show_error_message("Passwords do not match")
   return

 command = f'SELECT CAST(AES_DECRYPT(usuario, "{self.encryption_key}") AS CHAR) FROM cadastro_usuarios WHERE CAST(AES_DECRYPT(usuario, "{self.encryption_key}") AS CHAR) = "{self.nome_completo.text ()}"'
 self.cursor.execute(command)
 result = self.cursor.fetchone()

 if result is not None:
   self.show_error_message("This user has already been registered")
   return

 command = f'SELECT email FROM cadastro_usuarios WHERE email="{self.email_field.text()}"'
 self.cursor.execute(command)
 result = self.cursor.fetchone()

 if result is not None:
   self.show_error_message("This email has already been registered")
   return

 day = self.comboBox.currentText()
 mes = self.comboBox_2.currentText()
 year = self.comboBox_3.currentText()
 birth_date = f"{day}/{month}/{year}"
 command = (f'INSERT INTO cadastro_usuarios (user, birth_date, email, question, answer, password, avatar) '
 f'VALUES (AES_ENCRYPT("{self.full_name.text()}", "{self.encryption_key}"), '
 f'"{date_birth}", "{self.email_field.text()}", '
 f'AES_ENCRYPT("{self.comboBox_4.currentText()}", "{self.encryption_key}"), '
 f'AES_ENCRYPT("{self.resposta.text()}", "{self.encryption_key}"), '
 f'AES_ENCRYPT("{self.password_field_2.text()}", "{self.encryption_key}"), '
 f'"{self.image}")')
 self.cursor.execute(command)
 connection.commit()

 QMessageBox.information(self.centralwidget, "Success", "Data saved successfully")
 User.close()

At first I believed it was problems with opening and closing connections with MySQL, as screens interacting with each other, but all the ways I tried to modify this didn't work, either because the same problem persisted or even closed the application abruptly. I tried to make commands in MySQL after saving the registration to see if this delay passed to what was just registered and released the user, but without success either. I also tried to register the user only on the login screen and even so, I always need to close the interface and open it again to be able to use the data I registered with the bank, something that didn't happen before when I didn't have encryption.
